# Understanding a proof that the topologist's sine curve is not path connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness, path-connected

I have encountered a proof of the statement that the "The Topologist's sine curve is connected but not path connected" and I am not able to understand some part.

> **Example 5.2.23 (Topologist’s Sine Curve-I).**
>   Let
>   $$
>   A := \{ (x, \sin(\pi/x)) : 0 < x \leq 1 \}
>   \quad\text{and}\quad
>   B := \{ (0,y) : -1 \leq y \leq 1 \}.
> $$
>   Let $X = A \cup B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be given the induced metric topology.
>   We claim that $X$ is connected but not path connected.
>
> Let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to X$ be a path joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$.
>   We write $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$.
>   Since $B$ is closed in $X$, the inverse image $\gamma^{-1}(B)$ is closed, $0 \in \gamma^{-1}(B)$.
>   Let $t_0$ be the least upper bound of this closed and bounded set.
>   Obviously, $t_0 \in \gamma^{-1}(B)$.
>   Note that $0 < t_0 < 1$.
>   We claim that $\gamma_2$ is not continuous at $t_0$.
>
> For $\delta > 0$ with $t_0 + \delta \leq 1$ we must have $\gamma_1(t_0 + \delta) > 0$.
>   Hence there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gamma_1(t_0) < 2/(4n+1) < \gamma_1(t_0 + \delta)$.
>   By the intermediate value theorem applied to the continuous function $\gamma_1$, we can find $t$ such that $t_0 < t < t_0 + \delta$ and such that $\gamma_1(t) = 2/(4n+1)$.
>   Hence $\gamma_2(t) = 1$ and $|\gamma_2(t) - \gamma_2(t_0)| \geq 1$.
>   We therefore conlude that $\gamma_2$ is not continuous at $t_0$.
>
> (Original images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4id8e.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ER3l.png).)

My doubt here is whether if : 
 $t_0$ is Sup{$\gamma^{-1}(B)$}, 
B={$(0,y)|-1\leq y\leq 1$}
 then
why $\gamma_2(t_0)<0$ as there is statment that $|\gamma_2(t)-\gamma_2(t_0)|\geq 1$ ?[I know that value of $\gamma_2(t)=1$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Uniform continuity is the key here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\gamma_2(t_0) \le 0$ then the above argument works.

If $\gamma_2(t_0) \ge 0$, then replace $\frac{2}{4n+1}$ everywhere in the argument with $\frac{2}{4n-1}$ so that $\gamma_2(t) = -1$.

In either case you are able to find a $t \in (t_0, t_0 + \delta)$ such that $|\gamma_2(t) - \gamma_2(t_0)| \ge 1$.

Comment: The main point is, the second part is ignored in the excerpt from the book, and it ought not to be. At least it should've been mentioned in some way.