# Show that $\{(x,y): 0 < x \leq 1; y = \sin{1/x}\} \cup \{z: x = 0; -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, connectedness, path-connected

Show that $\{(x,y): 0 < x \leq 1; y = \sin{1/x}\} \cup \{z: x = 0; -1 \leq y \leq 1\}$ is not path connected. The book gives this set as an example of a closed, connected but not path connected set. I don't understand how it is possible though. The first component is continuous everywhere except $(0,0)$ and the second component contains $(0,0)$ too and is continuous on every point. Clearly they are path connected individually. Which are those 2 points one on the first component, the other on second component, that can't be connected with a curve from the given set?

Comment: Shouldn't your $z$ be $(x,y)$?

Comment: There is no path between _any_ point in the first component and _any_ point in the second component. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2890631/1508) for a slightly technical proof. But the intuition should be clear enough $-$ just try and draw it!

Comment: This is called the Topologists' Sine Curve, & this question has been asked before on this site. Search for it.

Comment: This has been asked **many** times. See https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=topologist%27s+sine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a path $f(t)=(a(t), b(t))$, $t\in [0, 1]$ and $f(0)$ is a point in the upright segment and $f(1)$ is a point on the given curve.  Then if $t_0$ such that the path $f$ leaves the upright segment then the limit $\lim_{t\to t_0^{+}} f(t)$ should exist with also $b(t)=\sin (1/t)$ for $t\in (t_0, 1]$. But arbitary near any point of the upright segment $b(t)$ takes values from $1 $ to $-1$.

**EDIT**
[image]

Consider a circle of arbritary small radius and center the point $A=f(t_0)$ then from the semi plane $x>0$ the topologist's sine curve goes in and out this circle infinity many times. That means that the path cannot be continuous near the point $A$, which is absurd.

Please also note that the continuous  path $f(t)$ lying in the semi plane $x>0$ may not have the parametrization of $f(t)=(t,\sin(1/t))$, (although I consider as such for simplicity) but in all cases should have the  same track of  the curve $(t,\sin(1/t)), t\in (0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply. But what is the geometric explanation to this? I can't find or I just don't understand the explanations in other posts

Comment: Welcome! Take the point on the upright segment , where the path leaves this segment and starts moving on the "sin" curve. The path should be continous so near this point,  (draw a small circle)  the "sin" curve should restrict to this small circle.  But due to it's nature,  it goes from height 1 to -1, so you cannot restrict it.  When I will be home I will draw some picture. @H-a-y-K

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand it now (though a bit late..)